# How can I re-publish an android app on Google play?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I had unpublished an app on Google play for some reason. Now I want to give it another shot and re-publish same app. I can't see any such option in Play Console.

Rolling out a new release didn't help.

Answer (score 2):

Its in Pricing and Distribution section of Google Play.

[image]